# Image scaling for iPhone 4-inch and 4.7-inch screens

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I'm trying to deal with images in iPhone 5 and 6 (let's forget the 6+ for now). I can do a lot of work arounds, but I'd like to know what's the best way to deal with images.

I have this image:

[image: Image@1x]

This image is 321x253 pixels. I'm working with its @2x size image too.

[image]

But obviously if I set the size as 321:

[image: Image with autolayout1]

As you can see the first preview is the `iPhone 4-inch` one and the second one is the `iPhone 4.7-inch`. It fits with the 4-inch screen, but I want both devices.

So I place this image edge to edge so:

[image: Image with autolayout2]

But the second one is stretched. Should I use different images for different width screens?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yep sure, you can see some rules in the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions:

- If you need to absolutely keep the same height for your picture, make a 2nd file with the correct dimensions.
- Otherwise, use autolayout to pin the width, the ratio and the origin of your UIImageView and select "Aspect fit" as View Mode.

Comment: The problem with the first option is I have to create another imagen set and use it just with that width? it still seem a bit work around. With the second option just I can't make it works.

Comment: My idea about this question is just to double check if it's normal we have to deal simple images, obviously now we have more dimension but it would be easy if we have the option to add image per screen size

Comment: If you can, the best practice is always to create an asset catalog that contains '@1x', '@2x' and '@3x' versions of your image.